# What is the correct name for the axis tick marks

Tags: geometry

What is the correct name for the major and minor tick marks that denote discrete points on an axis?

I believe the correct name is also synonym that has another meaning, but I just can't think of it.  I've drawn a blank :(

Comment: [Graduations](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/graduation)?